# What do Ken and Ryu say when they do their special moves?

Tags: street-fighter-series, street-fighter-ii

I know the there's hadōken (波動拳, wave-motion fist) for the ball of fire/plasma.

Does anyone know what they say for the jumping uppercut and the helicopter kick?

If the words changed over time, I'm particularly interested in what they say in Street Fighter II.

Comment: Related (for Brazilian at least): [Tiger Robocop e outras "Pérolas" de Street Fighter II](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjB6sgAfrJU). funny ways the special moves sound to non-english/japanese-speaker-children in the 90's :P (like `mini-taxi` (small cab) to Chun-li special attack)

Comment: Related: [Street Fighter Red Tape: Ryu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbHLQAthI7M)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The uppercut is known as the "Shoryuken", and that's what he says while executing it, while the kick is known as the "Tatsumaki Senpuu Kyaku" which he says while executing it, or the "Hurricane Kick" due to the tough pronunciation of the name.

[Source](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Ryu)

Comment: Guess I read the wrong wiki. =)

Comment: triple upvotes to you.  Shoryuken > Hadoken .. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Ryu's hurricane kick is called a [Tatsumaki](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Tatsumaki).  The full words is actually: "Tatsumaki Senpukyaku" Literal translation: "Tornado Whirlwind Leg"

His Dragon Uppercut is called [Shoryuken](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Shoryuken)

Answer (score 8):

The rising uppercut is called the "Shoryuken," and has remained the same since Street Fighter 2 (I'm actually surprised you know the word hadouken but not shoryuken, considering it's the most famous of the SF moves and even has a whole website named after it). I think it may list their names in the command list in the start menu of all the games since around Alpha. Anyway, it supposedly means rising dragon fist. The hurricane kick, or tornado whirlwind leg, is said as "Tatsumaki Senpuukyaku," but they say it so fast it sounds like gibberish.

Comment: I've had their voices embedded in my brain since SF2, but I never knew what the actual words were until today.

Comment: Hadouken is quite a bit more famous than shoryuken (although shoryuken is still quite famous). There's even a band called Hadouken because of how famous the move is.

Comment: @MrSmooth There's now an [open-source bit torrent client for .NET/Mono](http://www.hdkn.net/) too.

Answer (score 1):

Ryu says "ha plak plak ploo plak" during the helicopter kick in SF2

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help but LOL at this.

Answer (score -2):

When Ryu does the hurricane kick he says, "flapjack whirljack."

Comment: How to mix pancake batter: ↓ <∕ ← K